# need help to build linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am facing problem to create Linq query following is example
following are some data which is available in Db

```
data-

7604
76041010
7505
750511
```

and i have another number like which i need to search in above data like

```
1) 76041010 this number should take 76041010 code from above data
2) 760458688 this number should take 7604 code from above data
3) 7505110022 this number should take 750511 code from above data ,
```

I need to retrieve maximum matched number from db, I need query please help me to build linq query.

Comment: Any effort to show?

Comment: Are you using EntityFramework? What is the name of your db context? Can you post your models & controllers?

Comment: yes i am using entity framework, my db context is TradeComplianceContext

Comment: The return in the third scenario is `7505`. Shouldn't it be `750511`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the most elegant solution, but produces the result you're expecting:

```
var result = data.Select(x => x.ToString())
                 .Where(x => input.ToString().StartsWith(x))
                 .OrderByDescending(x => x.Length)
                 .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks for replay , but it should match 4 digit ,

Comment: your Linq query seems if 1st or 2nd digit match then also it return data

Comment: @kushalpawar how do you mean? could you give an example when it doesn't produce your expected result?

Comment: suppose  76111010 will return 76041010 becoz first 2 digits match with number , but  it should return null because 7611 number not available in db , it should check start with 4 digit or greater than 4 digit

Comment: @kushalpawar if you search for `76111010`, using the `data` from your question (with the 4 values), this code will return `null`

Comment: Yes, got it, now result is perfect.